# How to retrieve claims for current user in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2013

How do I retrieve Claims for current user in SharePoint 2013?

In earlier version (SP 2010/.NET 3.5), I could have used the below code, but the Claims related APIs have changed in .NET 4.5. Thus, what is the .NET 4.5 way of achieving the same?

```
IClaimsPrincipal cp = Page.User as IClaimsPrincipal;
IClaimsIdentity ci = (IClaimsIdentity)cp.Identity;
foreach (Claim c in ci.Claims)
{
}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. What error are you getting?

Comment: IClaimsPrincipal seem to be deprecated in .NET 4.5. And above works only if you refer WIF assembly. But, in .NET 4.5 Claims related APIs are built into the framework. So, I need to know how to achieve the same using .NET classes/interfaces?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
 ClientContext clientContext =
                TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(
                    sharepointUrl.ToString(), accessToken);



        //Load the properties for the Web object.
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //Get the site name.
        siteName = web.Title;

        //Get the current user.
        clientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName
```